# Pandas generate multiple CSV files on a loop

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to recreate what I achieved manually using a for loop
What I did was to manually written 10 CSV files.
the code is like this

```
     df_1.to_csv('eblist1.csv', encoding='latin-1', index=False)
     df_2.to_csv('eblist2.csv', encoding='latin-1', index=False)
     df_3.to_csv('eblist3.csv', encoding='latin-1', index=False)
     df_4.to_csv('eblist4.csv', encoding='latin-1', index=False)
     df_5.to_csv('eblist5.csv', encoding='latin-1', index=False)
     df_6.to_csv('eblist6.csv', encoding='latin-1', index=False)
     df_7.to_csv('eblist7.csv', encoding='latin-1', index=False)
     df_8.to_csv('eblist8.csv', encoding='latin-1', index=False)
     df_9.to_csv('eblist9.csv', encoding='latin-1', index=False)
     df_10.to_csv('eblist10.csv', encoding='latin-1', index=False)
```

That works fine as expected it writes all these files from my dataframes.
Then I tried to achieve the same thing using a loop ...
and here is where I got stuck, I spent hours reading at different solutions, and tried several options,
but I always end up getting a syntax error

```
     line 98, in <module>
names.to_csv('eblist'+str(res)+'.csv', encoding='latin-1', index=False)

     AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

The only thing I need is a way to add the value to the string, as the loop iterates through the dictionary, and believe me, I tried many approaches ...

```
      d = {'df_1':df_1,'df_2': df_2,'df_3': df_3,'df_4': df_4,'df_5': 
      df_5,'df_6': df_6,'df_7': df_7,'df_8': df_8,'df_9': df_9,'df_10': 
      df_10}

      for names in d:
          res = list(d.keys()).index(names) 
          names.to_csv('eblist'+str(res)+'.csv', encoding='latin-1', index=False)
```

Comment: my guess is that you don't even need to have this many dataframes. they should all be in one dataframe with an identifying column and a bunch of `groupby` operations

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message "'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'", it appears you attempted to access the to_csv() method from a string and not the class itself. You are on the right track. Assuming you have a list of your dataframes (the actual dataframes and not strings of the dataframes), then you should be able to do what you are looking for:

```
  dfs = [df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4, df_5, df_6, df_7, df_8, df_9, df_10]

  for index,df in enumerate(dfs,1):
      df.to_csv(f'eblist{index}.csv', encoding='latin-1', index=False)
```

Comment: improvement suggestion: `enumerate(dfs, 1)` to get rid of the `index+1` clutter inside the loop-body?

Comment: @StefanB Nice!!

Comment: @Bobby Ocean Thank you! My limited Python knowledge shows ;) ...  I upvoted your answer, that should do the trick!

Comment: also thanks to @StefanB for improving it!

Answer (score 0):

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

This is due to your loop:

```
for names in d:
```

This is iterating over the keys of your dictionary, which are strings. You actually never access to the values of your dictionary (the dataframes). If you really want to use a dictionary, just do:

```
for names, df in d.items():
    res = list(d.keys()).index(names) 
    df.to_csv('eblist'+str(res)+'.csv', encoding='latin-1', index=False)
```

Or better use a list instead of a dictionary as suggested in other answers, since it seems that you are interested in the position and the keys do not have any other meaning.